# Measurable sets of probability measures $\{\mu \in M: (\mu \times \mu)(A) \in B\} \in \mathscr{M}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathscr{F})$ be a measurable space, and let $M$ be the set all probability measures $\mu: \mathscr{F} \to [0,1]$. Let us denote with $\mathscr{M}$ the $\sigma$-algebra on $M$ generated by the mappings $\mu \mapsto \mu(F)$, with $F \in \mathscr{F}$.

Now fix a Borel set $B$ of $\mathbb{R}$ and $A \in \mathscr{F} \otimes \mathscr{F}$. How can we prove that
$$
\{\mu \in M: (\mu \times \mu)(A) \in B\} \in \mathscr{M}?
$$

[Here $(\mu\times \mu)$ stands for the product measure and $\mathscr{F}\otimes \mathscr{F}$ for the product $\sigma$-algebra]

[Linked thread on MSE: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1678329/measurability-of-product-measures-mu-in-m-mu-times-mua-in-b-in)]

Comment: Is this a homework exercise?

Comment: Not really, just a curiosity which I would like to solve (to be precise, I asked myself why a variant of deFinetti representation theorem was meaningful); I posted this morning the same problem on MSE, but it didn't receive much attention..

Comment: So in general it's considered impolite to simultaneously post to MO and MSE (it can lead to people duplicating work). The preferred strategy if you're not sure is to post to MSE; wait for a day or two before posting to MO. Also, when you do cross-post, make sure that each posting refers to the other.

Comment: I am sorry Anthony, I will take it into account next time.. I added the links to both threads, let me know if I forgot something..

Comment: Answered on Math.SE.